# How to restrict special characters in a certain form field using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like the user can only enter `1-9` and `aA-zZ`.

There are many codes on Stack Overflow, but each of them have some bugs.

Ex:

```
$('#username').bind('keypress', function (event) {
    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
    var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
    if (!regex.test(key)) {
        event.preventDefault();


        return false;
    }
});
```

The user is prevented to use backspace or delete keys!

Comment: `The user is prevented to use backspace or delete keys !!!` No, he isn't regarding your posted code. If so, on which browser are you testing it?

Comment: I'm using `firefox 43.0.1`;

Comment: Ya you are correct, FF prevents it

Comment: Use `keydown`, not `keypress`. Also, since you're using jQuery, use `on` not `bind` and use `event.which`, since jQuery normalizes `charCode` and `keyCode` to `which`.

Answer (score 0):

You could filter it out regrading `event.which` (which is normalized in jQuery) so your code would be:

```
var regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;

$('#username').on('keypress', function(event) {
  if (event.which === 8 || event.which === 0) return;

  var key = String.fromCharCode(event.which);
  return regex.test(key);
});
```

Comment: As I've suggested in my answer, you can also suggest `pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+"` on `input`.

Comment: @Tushar Ya for validation but still not supported by Safari AFAIK and if that matters

Comment: In that case we have JS validator. :). Almost all latest browsers support HTML5.

Comment: @Tushar There is partial support regarding pattern attribute on Safari http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-pattern